# Reverse RANK using MYSQL

Tags: mysql, rank

I have the following table

```
Member      Date Joined
------      -----------
Alan        01/02/2014
Bob         01/02/2013
Phil        01/02/2012
Bert        01/02/2011
```

but I would like to rank them in reverse order whilst keeping the results in Date Joined Order order. I.e I would like to output

```
No   Member      Date Joined
--   ------      ----------
4    Alan        01/02/2014
3    Bob         01/02/2013 
2    Phil        01/02/2012
1    Bert        01/02/2011
```

No sure where to start ? Any ideas anybody?

Comment: @FDL I assume it's the Date Joined.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the standard 'create row numbers' routine for MySQL within an inner query, then select from it in reverse order:

```
select
    member,
    date_joined
    rank
from (
    select 
        member,
        date_joined,
        @rank := @rank + 1 as rank
    from 
        members
        join (select @rank := 0) r
    order by 
        date_joined asc
) foo
order by rank desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your table is `myTable` and it has `member` and `date_joined` columns, try this query:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT IF(@prev <> date_joined, @s:=@s+1, @s:=@s) AS `rank`, 
  member, @prev:=date_joined date_joined
  FROM
  myTable, (SELECT @s:= 1, @prev:= 0) s
  ORDER BY date_joined
) t
ORDER BY rank DESC
```

The query keeps a counter variable `@s` which is incremented when `date_joined` value is different from previous record's date_joined value.